# How do I use gsed on macOS to replace a string with the contents of a file?

Tags: bash, text, sed, replace, macos-sierra

I need to take a text file, an index.html specifically, and insert the contents of another text file into a specific spot in that text file, but not at the end of the line.

I understand how to replace (substitute) the text with a string, as follows:

```
gsed 's/WHAT_TO_SUBSTITUTE/WHAT_TO_SUBSTITUTE_WITH/' index.html > index-new.html
```

However when I try to substitute with the contents of a file, I run into issues. Here's what I've tried:

```
gsed 's/<!--New Posts Go Below This Line-->/r newpost.txt/' index.html > index-new.html
```

The above does not work at all.

```
gsed -s '/<!--New Posts Go Below This Line-->/ r newentry.txt' index.html > index-new.html
```

The above inserts the contents of the file, but at the end of the line instead of substituting the string (as expected)

Contents of text file:

```
<!--New Posts Go Below This Line--> <div class=panel panel-default><div class=panel-heading><h4 class=panel-title><a data-parent=#accordion data-toggle=collapse href=#collapse56> February 31st, 2069 - New Post </a></h4></div><div class=panel-collapse collapse  id=collapse56><div class=panel-body><img alt=my_favorite_image.png div= src=/render/file.act?path=/my_favorite_image.png /></div></div></div>
```

Expected output (keep in mind, because of my company's CMS, the html I'm working with is one large block once written to the web server):

```
....index.html_HTML_code....<!--New Posts Go Below This Line-->CONTENTS_OF_newpost.txt.....index.html_HTML_code....
```

Comment: Show input sample with expected output.

Comment: I edited to provide an idea of my index.html and newpost.txt files, hopefully that helps.

Comment: Use Perl rather than mess about with the ancient, useless version of `sed` that Apple ships.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To replace `<!--New Posts Go Below This Line-->` with content from `newpost.html` you could stick with simple shell command substitution:

```
gsed "s/<!--New Posts Go Below This Line-->/$(cat newpost.txt)/" index.html > index-new.html
```

**Edit:**

This will only work, if newpost.txt does not contain newlines. Doing stuff with multiple lines with sed is very hard because the syntax is very obscure and hard to read.

I strongly recommend another tool for the job. For example Perl:

```
perl -pe 's/<!--New Posts Go Below This Line-->/`cat newpost.txt`/ge' index.html > index-new.html
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, I've tried that exact method, and it removes the substitution pattern, but doesn't enter the contents of the `newpost.txt` file

Comment: Ah. I think the problem are the newlines in the index.html. I did not think about that. Doing multiline stuff with (gnu) sed is very obscure. Do you need to stick with `(g)sed`?

Comment: I don't have to stick with `gsed`, I was just having more problems with `sed`, but that could have been because I was earlier on my learning curve with `sed` in the first place

Comment: @JohannesBarop: GNU sed handles new-lines better than the BSD version (the one shipped with OSX)

Comment: @Thor, that might be true, but still, the syntax is awful and hard to understand. I would rather use another tool for the job.

Comment: @hyraxai: Can you use Perl? Try this:

    perl -pe 's/<!--New Posts Go Below This Line-->/`cat newpost.txt`/ge' index.html > index-new.html

Comment: Sorry, I was unable to properly format the code in the comment box.

Comment: @JohannesBarop: Can you check your syntax for me? I'm not familiar with perl and I'm getting syntactic errors, and I tried adjusting to no avail. I'm certainly interested in the approach as an alternative though.

Comment: I updated the answer where code formatting seems to be working

Comment: @JohannesBarop: It seems to be working. Let me run a couple more tests before I mark the answer.

Comment: @JohannesBarop: Thank you! This is the approach I chose

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the match is on a line of its own you can insert the file and delete the pattern-space, e.g.:

*parse.sed*

```
/<!--New Posts Go Below This Line-->/ {
  r newentry.txt
  d
}
```

Run it like this:

```
sed -f parse.sed
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
sed $'/<!--New Posts Go Below This Line-->/ { r newentry.txt\n d; }'
```

#### Edit

If the match is a sub-string of the line, use `s///` instead of `d`, e.g.:

*parse.sed*

```
/<!--New Posts Go Below This Line-->/ {
  r newentry.txt
  s///
}
```

Comment: That deleted the entire HTML block (by block, I mean incredibly long line that I have soft wrapped in my editor for readability) that the pattern string was in lol, but I think you might be on to something.

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem, and if I didn't have to use the CMS for other things, I'd probably be fine...

Comment: that saved the giant html line, removed the substitution pattern, but placed the `newenrty.txt` on the next line

Comment: @Thor: Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: @hyraxai: That makes no sense, unless you are using a different pattern

Comment: I likely used your example incorrectly. Regardless, I appreciate the help; I learned some new things.